# Boxplot of disease vs control genes in R

Tags: r, boxplot

New to R so no idea about it. I have a data of 64 samples (AML disease vs Control) and 22283 genes expression value of each sample. The data looks like this.

| GSM239170 | GSM239323 | GSM239324 | GSM239326 | GSM239328 | GSM239329 | GSM239331 | GSM239332 | GSM239333 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.016704177 | 3.285669072 | 2.929482692 | 2.922820483 | 3.15950317 | 3.163327169 | 2.985901308 | 3.122708843 | 3.070948463 |
| 7.977735461 | 6.532514237 | 6.388007183 | 6.466679556 | 6.432795021 | 6.407321524 | 6.426470803 | 6.376394357 | 6.469070308 |
| 4.207280707 | 4.994965767 | 4.40159671 | 4.747114589 | 4.830045513 | 4.213762092 | 4.884418365 | 4.4318876 | 4.849665444 |
| 7.25609471 | 7.420807337 | 6.999340125 | 7.094488581 | 7.024332721 | 7.17928981 | 7.159898654 | 7.009977785 | 6.830979234 |
| 2.204955099 | 2.331625217 | 2.133305231 | 2.18332885 | 2.12778313 | 2.269697813 | 2.264705552 | 2.253940441 | 2.287924323 |
| 7.28437278 | 6.983593721 | 6.86337111 | 6.865970678 | 7.219840938 | 7.181113053 | 7.392230178 | 7.484052914 | 7.52498281 |
| 4.265792764 | 4.970684112 | 4.595545125 | 4.575545289 | 4.547957809 | 4.68215122 | 4.674495889 | 4.675841709 | 4.643311767 |
| 2.6943516 | 2.916324936 | 2.578130269 | 2.659717988 | 2.567436676 | 2.8095128 | 2.790110381 | 2.795882913 | 2.884588792 |
| 3.646303109 | 8.817891552 | 11.4248793 | 10.74738082 | 9.296043108 | 9.53150669 | 8.285160496 | 9.769919327 | 9.774610531 |
| 3.040292001 | 3.38486713 | 2.958851115 | 3.047880699 | 2.878562717 | 3.209319974 | 3.20260379 | 3.195993624 | 3.3004227 |
| 2.357625231 | 2.444753172 | 2.340767158 | 2.32143889 | 2.282608342 | 2.401218719 | 2.385568421 | 2.375334953 | 2.432634747 |
| 5.378494673 | 6.065038394 | 5.134842087 | 5.367342376 | 5.682051149 | 5.712072512 | 5.57179966 | 5.72082395 | 5.656674512 |
| 2.833814735 | 3.038434511 | 2.837711812 | 2.859800224 | 2.866040813 | 2.969167906 | 2.929449968 | 2.963530689 | 2.931065261 |
| 6.192932281 | 6.478439634 | 6.180169144 | 6.151689376 | 6.238949956 | 6.708196123 | 6.441437631 | 6.448280595 | 6.413562269 |
| 4.543042482 | 4.786227217 | 4.445131477 | 4.51471011 | 4.491645167 | 4.460114204 | 4.602482637 | 4.587221948 | 4.623125028 |
| 6.069437462 | 6.232738284 | 6.74644117 | 7.04995802 | 6.938928532 | 6.348253102 | 6.080950712 | 6.324619355 | 6.472893789 |

Where (**GSM239170, GSM239323, GSM239324, GSM239332, GSM239333**) are AML samples and (**GSM239326, GSM239328, GSM239329, GSM239331**) are Control samples. I want to make a Boxplot of gene expression for all the samples, marking data points in red for AML samples and blue for Control samples.

I tried the following code, but got the error.

```
boxplot(df1, main = "Boxplot")
```

> Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] :    non-numeric argument to
> binary operator

And with this code,

```
meltData <- melt(df1)
boxplot(meltData, main = "Boxplot")
# Error
meltData <- melt(df1)
Using Probe_ID as id variables
boxplot(meltData, main = "Boxplot")
Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

How I can make the boxplot?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `boxplot(value ~ variable, meltData, main = "Boxplot")`. This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, but how I can mark data points in red for AML samples and blue for Control samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To color the AML and Control red and blue, respectively, match the `names(df1)` to the AML vector and use it to index a vector of color values.

```
meltData <- reshape2::melt(df1)

aml <- scan(text="GSM239170, GSM239323, GSM239324, GSM239332, GSM239333", what = character(), sep = ",")
aml <- trimws(aml)
i_aml <- (names(df1) %in% aml) + 1L
colors <- c("blue", "red")

boxplot(value ~ variable, meltData, main = "Boxplot", col = colors[i_aml])
```

[image]

---

### Data

```
df1 <-
structure(list(GSM239170 = c(3.016704177, 7.977735461, 4.207280707, 
7.25609471, 2.204955099, 7.28437278, 4.265792764, 2.6943516, 
3.646303109, 3.040292001, 2.357625231, 5.378494673, 2.833814735, 
6.192932281, 4.543042482, 6.069437462), GSM239323 = c(3.285669072, 
6.532514237, 4.994965767, 7.420807337, 2.331625217, 6.983593721, 
4.970684112, 2.916324936, 8.817891552, 3.38486713, 2.444753172, 
6.065038394, 3.038434511, 6.478439634, 4.786227217, 6.232738284
), GSM239324 = c(2.929482692, 6.388007183, 4.40159671, 6.999340125, 
2.133305231, 6.86337111, 4.595545125, 2.578130269, 11.4248793, 
2.958851115, 2.340767158, 5.134842087, 2.837711812, 6.180169144, 
4.445131477, 6.74644117), GSM239326 = c(2.922820483, 6.466679556, 
4.747114589, 7.094488581, 2.18332885, 6.865970678, 4.575545289, 
2.659717988, 10.74738082, 3.047880699, 2.32143889, 5.367342376, 
2.859800224, 6.151689376, 4.51471011, 7.04995802), GSM239328 = c(3.15950317, 
6.432795021, 4.830045513, 7.024332721, 2.12778313, 7.219840938, 
4.547957809, 2.567436676, 9.296043108, 2.878562717, 2.282608342, 
5.682051149, 2.866040813, 6.238949956, 4.491645167, 6.938928532
), GSM239329 = c(3.163327169, 6.407321524, 4.213762092, 7.17928981, 
2.269697813, 7.181113053, 4.68215122, 2.8095128, 9.53150669, 
3.209319974, 2.401218719, 5.712072512, 2.969167906, 6.708196123, 
4.460114204, 6.348253102), GSM239331 = c(2.985901308, 6.426470803, 
4.884418365, 7.159898654, 2.264705552, 7.392230178, 4.674495889, 
2.790110381, 8.285160496, 3.20260379, 2.385568421, 5.57179966, 
2.929449968, 6.441437631, 4.602482637, 6.080950712), GSM239332 = c(3.122708843, 
6.376394357, 4.4318876, 7.009977785, 2.253940441, 7.484052914, 
4.675841709, 2.795882913, 9.769919327, 3.195993624, 2.375334953, 
5.72082395, 2.963530689, 6.448280595, 4.587221948, 6.324619355
), GSM239333 = c(3.070948463, 6.469070308, 4.849665444, 6.830979234, 
2.287924323, 7.52498281, 4.643311767, 2.884588792, 9.774610531, 
3.3004227, 2.432634747, 5.656674512, 2.931065261, 6.413562269, 
4.623125028, 6.472893789)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by pivoting your data, recoding in a new variable and ploting. I'm doing this example with the `tidyverse` collection of packages (tidyr, dplyr, ggplot2, etc).

First we load the packages and I'm creating a temporal dataset for this example. You can apply this to your own data.

Let's say I have a dataset with four columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tmp <- data.frame(col1 = runif(10),
           col2 = runif(10),
           col3 = runif(10),
           col4 = runif(10)) 

tmp
#>          col1      col2      col3      col4
#> 1  0.90734014 0.5982927 0.8737742 0.4736948
#> 2  0.86152607 0.6449016 0.8081259 0.4717687
#> 3  0.82432693 0.1984189 0.8673977 0.2029126
#> 4  0.85152294 0.2304586 0.6021387 0.3914528
#> 5  0.38723829 0.5963829 0.6431011 0.8964814
#> 6  0.45445156 0.2750627 0.8670836 0.3399746
#> 7  0.38512391 0.5757645 0.9060044 0.1580425
#> 8  0.58636619 0.4287894 0.7827405 0.6647625
#> 9  0.50576266 0.6141626 0.5411717 0.4168770
#> 10 0.06328743 0.1455354 0.7490322 0.9065379
```

I know col1 and col2 are control groups, soy I need to pivot all my columns and create a *type* column to identify the control and treatment group. I've previously created the `control_cols` vector to have cleaner code. I think if you are new to R, the quickest way is to specify the 32 names manually. If you happen to know about regular expressions you can take advantage of that by using `str_detect()` in the *colnames* column.

```r
control_cols <- c("col1", "col2")

tmp_transformed <- tmp %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "colname", values_to = "value") %>% 
  mutate(type = if_else(colname %in% control_cols, "control", "treatment"))

tmp_transformed
#> # A tibble: 40 x 3
#>    colname value type     
#>    <chr>   <dbl> <chr>    
#>  1 col1    0.907 control  
#>  2 col2    0.598 control  
#>  3 col3    0.874 treatment
#>  4 col4    0.474 treatment
#>  5 col1    0.862 control  
#>  6 col2    0.645 control  
#>  7 col3    0.808 treatment
#>  8 col4    0.472 treatment
#>  9 col1    0.824 control  
#> 10 col2    0.198 control  
#> # ... with 30 more rows
```

Once my data is ready i can now create a boxplot where each fill color is mapped to a group type. You can specify the colors manually inside `scale_fill_manual()`.

For control vs treatment:

```r
tmp_transformed %>% 
  ggplot(aes(type, value, fill = type)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("cyan", "red"))
```

[image]

For colname and type

```r
tmp_transformed %>% 
  ggplot(aes(colname, value, fill = type)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("cyan", "red"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks but in my case, how I can specify column names (note there are 64 columns in the data) as you did in  ```c("col1", "col2"), "control", "treatment"```. Do I have to manually write the column names in the code?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include this. Short answer: if you are new to programming, yes.